# Нажатие на submit средствами php

Tags: ооп, php, классы

Доброго времени суток! В общем я хотел поинтересоваться как с помощью php кода якобы "нажимают" на submit? то есть авторегеры на пример. они заполняют формы и нажимают на submit, как можно сделать такое на php? хотел сделать регер или логин, если к примеру вводят логин и пароль на моём сайте что бы я мог его авторизовать и на другом сайте с этим же логином и паролем. Если можно с комментариями в коде )

Comment: Пардон, но если вы 2 года на ресурсе довольно активно и еще не поняли различие между серверными и клиентскими языками - закажите авторегер на фрилансе что ли...

ЗЫ: google: wiki http, php curl, php cookie, php referer, wiki user agent, [...]

Comment: Позвольте офигеть с вашего вопроса. Вы путаете действия сервера и браузера.

Comment: @bazaev05, в интернете предостаточно информации на эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило, в большинстве случаев достаточно на URL, указанный в атрибуте `action` тега `form` отправить запрос типа, который указа в атрибуте `method`.

В запросе отправляете параметры, которые собираются у элементов `input`. Атрибут `name` - это имя параметра, а значением будет то, что введено в `input`